# convert FiX message to JSON using JAVA

Tags: json, string, fix-protocol

i have extracted the fix message as below  from Unix server and now need to convert this message into JSON. how can we do this?

8=FIXT.1.1|9=449|11=ABCD1|35=AE|34=1734|49=REPOFIXUAT|52=20140402-11:38:34|56=TR_UAT_VENDOR|1128=8|15=GBP|31=1.7666|32=50000000.00|55=GBP/USD|60=20140402-11:07:33|63=B|64=20140415|65=OR|75=20140402|150=F|167=FOR|194=1.7654|195=0.0012|460=4|571=7852455|1003=2 USD|1056=88330000.00|1057=N|552=1|54=2|37=20140402-12:36:48|11=NOREF|453=4|448=ZERO|447=D|452=3|448=MBY2|447=D|452=1|448=LMEB|447=D|452=16|448=DOR|447=D|452=11|826=0|78=1|79=default|80=50000000.00|5967=88330000.00|10=111

Answer (score 1):

Note: I tried to make this a comment on the answer provided by @selbie, but the text was too long for a comment, so I am making it an answer.

@selbie's answer will work most of the time, but there are two edge cases in which it could fail.

First, in a `tag=value` field where the `value` is of type `STRING`, it is legal for `value` to contain the `=` character. To correctly cope with this possibility, the Java statement:

```
pair = item.split("=");
```

should be changed to:

```
pair = item.split("=", 2);
```

The second edge case is when there are a pair of fields, the first of which is of type `LENGTH` and the second is of type `DATA`. In this case, the value of the `LENGTH` fields specifies the length of the `DATA` field (without the delimiter), and it is legal for the value of the `DATA` field to contain the delimiter character (ASCII character 1, but denoted as `|` in both the question and Selbie's answer). Selbie's code cannot be modified in a trivial manner to deal with this edge case. Instead, you will need a more complex algorithm that consults a FIX data dictionary to determine the type of each field.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't tag your question for any particular programming language, I'll give you a few sample solutions:

In javascript:

```
let s = "8=FIXT.1.1|9=449|11=ABCD1|35=AE|34=1734|49=REPOFIXUAT|52=20140402-11:38:34|56=TR_UAT_VENDOR|1128=8|15=GBP|31=1.7666|32=50000000.00|55=GBP/USD|60=20140402-11:07:33|63=B|64=20140415|65=OR|75=20140402|150=F|167=FOR|194=1.7654|195=0.0012|460=4|571=7852455|1003=2 USD|1056=88330000.00|1057=N|552=1|54=2|37=20140402-12:36:48|11=NOREF|453=4|448=ZERO|447=D|452=3|448=MBY2|447=D|452=1|448=LMEB|447=D|452=16|448=DOR|447=D|452=11|826=0|78=1|79=default|80=50000000.00|5967=88330000.00|10=111"

let obj = {};
items = s.split("|")
items.forEach(item=>{
    let pair = item.split("=");
    obj[pair[0]] = pair[1];
});

let jsonString = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

Python:

```
import json

s = "8=FIXT.1.1|9=449|11=ABCD1|35=AE|34=1734|49=REPOFIXUAT|52=20140402-11:38:34|56=TR_UAT_VENDOR|1128=8|15=GBP|31=1.7666|32=50000000.00|55=GBP/USD|60=20140402-11:07:33|63=B|64=20140415|65=OR|75=20140402|150=F|167=FOR|194=1.7654|195=0.0012|460=4|571=7852455|1003=2 USD|1056=88330000.00|1057=N|552=1|54=2|37=20140402-12:36:48|11=NOREF|453=4|448=ZERO|447=D|452=3|448=MBY2|447=D|452=1|448=LMEB|447=D|452=16|448=DOR|447=D|452=11|826=0|78=1|79=default|80=50000000.00|5967=88330000.00|10=111"
obj = {}
for item in s.split("|"):
    pair = item.split("=")
    obj[pair[0]] = pair[1]

jsonString = json.dumps(obj)
```

Porting the above solutions to other languages is an exercise for yourself.  There's comments below about semantic ordering and handling cases where the the `=` or `|` chars are part of the content. That's on you to explore if you need to support those scenarios.

Comment: thanks for response. happy to get in Java Language

Comment: See my answer for a discussion of two edge cases not handled by your code.

Comment: D'oh! I just noticed that you are putting the tag-value pairs into a dictionary. Prior to Python 3.7, dictionaries were unsorted. I'm not familiar with the modern Java `{}` syntax, but I'm guessing that is an empty unsorted map too. The order of fields in a FIX message is semantically important, for example, header fields must come before the body fields, which in turn must come before the trailer fields. In addition, if there are any repeating groups in a FIX message, then a tag might appear multiple times. For these reasons, the parsed tag-value pairs should be put into an array or list.

Comment: BTW it is also possible that `|` is included in a String field, so that is another edge case, at least when you split the message around `|`.

Comment: This is fair feedback. I made the working assumption that the original string would not have spurious `=` or `|` pipe chars within the text fields.  And I'm also guessing that the OP just wanted someone to write some code for him - and since I wasn't getting paid. So he gets sample code, not necessarily production code.

Comment: @Vipin - Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Since you didn't tag your question with any particular programming language, you get the answer you get. I'm certain you can follow the sample solutions for Javascript and Python and apply to Java using the Split method on its String class.  Ciaran and Christoph make good points to consider, but that' out of scope for what I have to provide for.

Comment: @CiaranMcHale - Correct on the semantic ordering thing. I made the assumption that the OP didn't care about semantic ordering or using object vs array. I would suggest if ordering is important, then the correct usage would be to output a json array instead of a json object.  The OP's question was sufficiently vague such that assumptions had to be made.